# Is it possible to retrieve the posted form fields from within a parameterless HttpPost action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

**Non-HttpPost**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = repository.GetModel(id);
    if(model==null) return View("NotFound");
    return View(model);
}
```

**HttpPost**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
   // First of all, we retrieve the id from the posted form field. 
   // But I don't know how to do.


   var model = repository.GetModel(id);
   if(model==null) return View("NotFound");

   if(!TryUpdateModel(model))
     return View(model);

   repository.SaveChanges();
   RedirectToAction("Status","Controller");
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve the posted form fields from within a parameterless HttpPost action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posted form values:

```
var id = Request.Form["id"];
```

or:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection fc)
{
    var id = fc["id"];
    ...
}
```

or for any request value (including form posted):

```
var id = Request["id"];
```

Comment: @user596314, yes, assuming `Request["id"]` is a valid integer.